# Expandable rows with lazy loading not working correctly when using clrIfExpandedChange

Tags: datagrid, vmware-clarity

When using expandable rows with `clrLoading`(for lazy loading) and with `clrIfExpandedChange`, the row starts to expand then closes(for the loading) and finally opens. Is there a way to disable the slight expansion is makes right when you click?

My row details looks like this:

```
  <clr-dg-row-detail clrIfExpanded (clrIfExpandedChange)="func(user)">
    <div [clrLoading]="isLoading">Lorem ipsum...</div>
  </clr-dg-row-detail>
```

Example of the behavior on stack blitz:
https://stackblitz.com/edit/clarity-light-theme-v2-o6nez4

Thanks!

Comment: It looks like you may have found a bug with the internal services for the loading state of expandable rows. Could you open a new bug report with your reproduction and reference the question here? https://github.com/vmware/clarity/issues/new/choose